# Django admin export model with inlines to csv

Tags: python, django, django-admin, export, inlines

I try to find a way to export a model with inlines to csv with a button or action in django admin. Has anyone done this before?

I've already tried to export with django_import_export but i haven't found a way to get the content of the inlines.

The goal of the export is to export a contract with n products and n subproducts.

Thank you all for the help

Comment: refer this --> https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/packages/2016/08/11/django-import-export.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. i'm able to export a list of contracts or products but my goal is to export one or many contracts with the products (and subproducts) in it.